# Command history in Zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history

How does Zsh keep track of command history?

I see two files in my home directory: `.zhistory` and `.zsh_history`. What is the difference between them? The files seem to contain **all** of my history. Does Zsh keep appending lines to one of them *forever*? Wouldn't that make 
history search too slow?

Can I safely make these files symbolic links to another location? (e.g. a git repository to keep track of changes to the history)

Comment: Check your `~/.zshrc` and/or `/etc/zshrc` for options described there http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l17

Comment: if you are using ohmyzsh, here's the link to their documentation for per-directory-history: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/per-directory-history

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Zsh stores input lines (possibly with time information) in the file indicated by the variable [`HISTFILE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTFILE). This should be an absolute file name (otherwise it will be interpreted relative to whatever directory is current at the time).

Zsh has no built-in default value for `HISTFILE`. The zsh distribution comes with a setup wizard for new users which has the value `~/.histfile` built in, so this is what zsh users get by default. Oh-my-zsh comes with `HISTFILE=.zhistory` preset. So it looks like you tried zsh both with the default setup and with oh-my-zsh. Check your `.zshrc` (or the file dates) to see which one you're currently using.

How zsh opens the file, and therefore what happens if it is a symbolic link, depends on several options.

- If one of the options [`append_history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-APPEND_005fHISTORY) (set by default),  [`inc_append_history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-INC_005fAPPEND_005fHISTORY) or [`share_history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-SHARE_005fHISTORY) is set, or when the history is saved explicitly with `fc -AI`, zsh appends to the existing file.
  Note that even under these settings, zsh occasionally overwrite the file as described below to trim it down to size.
- Otherwise, if the option [`hist_save_by_copy`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HISTSAVEBYCOPY) is set (it's set by default since zsh 5.0, but does not exist in 4.2), zsh writes a temporary file then moves it in place when complete. In this case, if the history file was a symbolic link, the new file replaces the symbolic link.
- Otherwise zsh overwrites the existing file in place.

Rather than point zsh to a symbolic link, set `HISTFILE` to wherever you want the history file to be.

How many lines of history are kept is configured through the variables [`HISTSIZE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTSIZE) and  [`SAVEHIST`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-SAVEHIST). `HISTSIZE` is the maximum number of lines that are kept in a session and `SAVEHIST` is the maximum number of lines that are kept in the history file.

To get some history saved at all, you need to set both `HISTFILE` and `SAVEHIST`, as the default value of `SAVEHIST` is 0. You may want to increase `HISTSIZE` as well (as of zsh 5.0, the default is only 30).

Comment: When I open different terminal connect into same remote machine, they don't see each others newly entered command history. Is it possible to let them see each others recently entered commands?

Comment: @alper Yes, if you set `inc_append_history`.

Comment: I have following configuration (https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/9d826ae3676174b01648ad82e603a798)  in my `.zprofile` (`inc_append_history` is included). When I open two window on a terminal. And do `echo world_1` on first one, and `echo world_2` on the seconds one, they don't see each others commands on the history. But third new terminal sees them

Comment: You may have answered my question: Until I recently began digging into the **history** feature in `zsh`, I've assumed that ALL history was history that was stored in the history file. It's only occurred to me recently that there is also ***session*** history - which is stored in memory (??), and may or may not be in the history file depending on how certain options are set. Is that an accurate synopsis of it... two "memories" - one cached and one in a file?

Comment: @Seamus Yes. Each instance of the shell keeps its own history in memory, and in addition there's a history file. Several settings control when history entries get written to the file: `SAVEHIST`, `append_history`, `share_history`, …

Comment: And the *cached/session history* is manipulated via the `fc` commands as shown (for example) in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544815/286615)?

Comment: could you add to this illustrious answer, also a link about USING the history? how to retrieve a command 100 lines ago, or the last 5, or the first one today? how to "repeat last command" ?