# history shows only current session

Tags: zsh, command-history

This is what I see in my terminal in a fresh session:

```
Agent pid 6847
Identity added: /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa)
➜  ~  history
    1  history
➜  ~
```

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 64 bit and oh-my-zsh (ZSH shell).

This machine is newly set up.

This has never happened to my previous Fedora, Ubuntu or OS X machines.

What can I do so that history show more than current session - that should be the purpose of the **history** command in the first place right?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals/80882#80882

Answer (score 1):

Read you shell's manual to figure out how to configure persistent command line history.

In most shells, this is accomplished by setting the shell variable `HISTFILE` to the name of a file.  For example:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.shell_history
```

Bash uses `~/.bash_history` as the default history file, `ksh93` has no default (according to its manual), nor does `zsh`.

The `zsh` manual has *long* sections on various options and variables that influences how and when the command line history is saved and used, but the most important bit is to make sure that `HISTFILE` is set to the pathname of a writable file.

Related question: [Command history in Zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111718/command-history-in-zsh)