# How to clear history in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history

I'm looking for the zsh equivalent of the bash command `history -c`, in other words, clear the history for the current session. In zsh `history -c` returns 1 with an error message `history: bad option: -c`.

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for a way to delete the contents of `$HISTFILE`, I just want a command to reset the history to the same state it was in when I opened the terminal. Deleting the contents of `$HISTFILE` does the opposite of what I want: it deletes the history I want to preserve and preserves the history I want to delete (since current session's history would get appended to it, regardless if its contents was previously erased).

There is a workaround I use for now, but it's obviously less than ideal: in the current session I set `HISTFILE=/dev/null` and just close and reopen the terminal. This causes the history of the closed session not be appended to `$HISTFILE`. However, I'd really like something like `history -c` from bash, which is much more elegant than having to close and restart the terminal.

Comment: What history-related shell options are you using? Are you, for example, sharing history between shell sessions with `setopt SHARE_HISTORY` or are you using `setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY`  (both of these writes commands to the history as they are entered)?

Comment: I am using `setopt APPEND_HISTORY`. I'm quite happy with how that works, it appends the current session's history to the `$HISTFILE` whenever the terminal is closed. But sometimes I want to clear the history during the session (when I write something stupid), but preserve what is in `$HISTFILE`

Comment: are you looking for `history -p`?

Comment: It seems like you could use the title like: "How to reset the zsh histroy to a predefined set when I login", otherwise you will keep seeing "history -p" around

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get an empty history, temporarily set [`HISTSIZE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTSIZE) to zero.

```
function erase_history { local HISTSIZE=0; }
erase_history
```

If you want to erase the new history from this shell instance but keep the old history that was loaded initially, empty the history as above then reload the saved history `fc -R` afterwards.

If you don't want the `erase_history` call to be recorded in the history, you can filter it out in the [`zshaddhistory` hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-zshaddhistory).

```
function zshaddhistory_erase_history {
  [[ $1 != [[:space:]]#erase_history[[:space:]]# ]]
}
zshaddhistory_functions+=(zshaddhistory_erase_history)
```

---

Deleting one specific history element (`history -d NUM` in bash) is another matter. I don't think there's a way other than:

1. Save the history: `fc -AI` to append to the history file, or `fc -WI` to overwrite the history file, depending on your history sharing preferences.
2. Edit the history file (`$HISTFILE`).
3. Reload the history file: `fc -R`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good enough workaround that gives the result that I wanted. The only issue I have with it that the call to the `erase_history` function gets appended to the `HISTFILE` and thus remembered, but that's a minor inconvenience. I can run a script that erases every instance of `erase_history` from the `HISTFILE`.

Comment: @Kresimir Since a few versions ago you can filter which commands enter the history with a `zshaddhistory` hook. See my edit.

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't work. The hook works (if I add `echo TEST` to the `zshaddhistory_erase_history` function it echos it on every prompt), but the `erase_history` still gets added to the `HISTFILE`. I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: However, I thought of a workaround. If I use `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` I can call `erase_history` with a space in front of it and it will not get added to the `HISTFILE`.

Comment: @Kresimir Works for me: https://pastebin.com/Ct4JVjYX with 5.4.2. Maybe you don't have `extended_glob` turned on? That would cause `#` not to be a wildcard. I didn't think of it because pretty much everyone has it on.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Forgot to turn on `EXTENDED_GLOB`... Thanks for your help! I learnt a lot today.

Comment: well you can do it using the old and simple `kill -9 $$`. If you terminate you session this way you'll get nothing written to history.

Answer (score 52):

The equivalent to `history -c` on zsh is `history -p`

Comment: This has been suggested twice in (now-deleted) answers, and OP's response was "It works, but it does not do what the question asks"

Comment: I think the equivalent to `history -cw` on bash is `history -p` on zsh?

Comment: Note that `history -p` in zsh doesn't include the `history -p` command itself. In bash, it removes the command itself from history

Comment: This works perfectly. thanks :)

Comment: OP should have state that in title he/she wanted to restore history to a previous state.

Answer (score 8):

Try running the following command:

```
kill -9 $$
```

It will kill the current terminal without saving session history.

The following may be useful too:

```
rm -f ~/.zsh_history && kill -9 $$
```

This will remove the history file and kill the current terminal without saving session history.

Comment: This works (leaving no trace) in macOS Catalina. I suspect it works on other versions and platforms as well because of *how* it works.

Comment: For me, `kill -9 $$` still saves the session history. (It does kill the current terminal, though.) (Also, I'm using macOS, btw.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked as expected on macOS Sonoma. Thx

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Gimi 's answer but a bit more gentle, instead of removing the file I erase all of it's content.

```bsh
echo -n > ~/.zsh_history
```

or

```bsh
:>.zsh_history
```

Comment: `:>.zsh_history` super cute!