Make commands available in Zsh history right after you quit the macOS Terminal
Zsh 5.9, macOS 14.6.1, Terminal.app. A simple test:
Open Terminal, type echo test, press the Return key, then quit Terminal (that is, press Command-Q, not Command-W).
Open the Terminal again and press the Arrow Up key. You might expected to see echo test, but until you close the Terminal window using Command-W, echo test won't populate in your Arrow Up (or Control-R) history.
It seems that iTerm2 doesn't have such an issue. Can I fix it using Zsh itself? Or I should simply use iTerm2 instead if I want the history to work in such a way?

Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670027.
